# Add a new language to source-highlight

Tags: source-highlighting

I created a new language file and added it to [source-highlight](https://www.gnu.org/software/src-highlite/)'s language directory (`/usr/local/cellar/source-highlight/3.1.7/share/source-highlight`), but when I run `$ source-highlight --lang-list`, it isn't listed.

What do I need to do to register the language with source-highlight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to add the language to the `lang.map` file:

```
# crystal reports formula language
crystal = crystal.lang
```

Comment: Where did you find the `crystal.lang` file? or did you write it?

Comment: Wrote one (mostly complete): [A TextMate bundle for the Crystal Report's formula language](https://github.com/craibuc/crystal-reports-tmbundle).